# VLC command line issue

Tags: vlc

Im very confused , the following command does not work it just opens the video , how ever if i stream manually using GUI it streams perfectly ,

i used the same code for other streams but for some reason its hit or miss whether it works or not

vlc http://192.168.1.213:8866/live?channel=3&client=1 --transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,scale=Auto}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/} :sour-keep

Also tried
vlc -vvv http://192.168.1.213:8866/live?channel=3&client=1 --transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,scale=Auto}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/} :sour-keep

and tried

--sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=700,vfilter=deinterlace,fps=25,scale=Auto,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ts,dst=:8080/} :sout-keep

could someone shed some light on why the command is hit or miss for different links and any mistakes i have made
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it without the `:sout-keep´ at the end? I suppose you simply want to stream without keeping a stream output open?

Answer (score -1):

I would try to do it like this:

> --sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=700,vfilter=deinterlace,fps=25,scale=Auto,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8080/}"